# A formal proof required using real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

If $\int_0^1f^{2n}(x)dx=0$, prove that $f(x)=0$, where $f$ is a real valued continuous function on [0,1]?

It is obvious, since $f^{2n}(x) \geq 0$, the only way this is possible is when $f(x)=0$.

I am looking for any other formal way of writing this proof i.e. using concepts from real analysis.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest supposing $f(c)\ne 0$ for some $c$, say it is equal to $d$. Then by the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity, there is an interval (or half-interval, if $c$ is an endpoint) in which $|f(x)|\gt \frac{|d|}{2}$.

Comment: This is supposed to involve the definition of the integral, or results about the integral you are allowed to use, to justify the phrase "the only way this is possible".

Comment: @ Nicolas Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume there exists $c\in[0,1]$ such that $f^{2n}(x)>0$, then by definition of continuity there exists $0<\delta< \min(c,1-c)$ such that $$|x-c|<\delta\implies |f^{2n}(x)-f^{2n}(c)|<\frac{1}{2} f^{2n}(c)$$
Especially, if $|x-c|<\delta$ then $f^{2n}(x)>\frac{1}{2} f^{2n}(c)$. Therefore
$$\int_0^1 f^{2n}(x) dx =\int_0^{c-\delta} f^{2n}(x) dx+\int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} f^{2n}(x) dx+\int_{c+\delta}^1 f^{2n}(x) dx\\
\ge 0+2\delta \int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta} \frac{f^{2n}(c)}{2} dx+0 >0 $$