# Let $f(x)$ be continuous on [$0,1$] to $f(x)=0$ for each $x\in[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be continuous on [$0,1$] such that $f(x) \ge 0$  for each $x\in[0,1]$.If $\int^{1}_{0}f(x)dx = 0$ , Show that $f(x)=0$ for each $x\in[0,1]$

---

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/388201/53976)

Comment: A similar question has been answered just before this question. Please refer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:-

$f(x)$ is continuous. Suppose $f(x)>0$ at some point $x=a$. Then we can find an interval $[a-\delta , a+\delta]$ such that $f(x)>0$ on that interval.